# How to make Thread function self contained

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am reading "C++ Concurrency in Action".
I have following doubt with the below code snippet.

```
struct func
{
   int& i;
   func(int& i_):i(i_){}
   void operator()()
   {
       for(unsigned j=0;j<1000000;++j)
       {
           do_something(i); //Can have issue of dangling references
       }
   }
};

void oops()
{
    int some_local_state=0;
    func my_func(some_local_state);
    std::thread my_thread(my_func); 
    my_thread.detach();
}
```

The author says in order to avoid such scenario one way is to 
**make the thread function self-contained and copy the data into the thread rather than sharing the data**

I do understand the problem is because of the fact the function object created is local to the oop function and when the oops function finishes the object goes out of scope, but I cannot understand how to avoid in way author has mentioned it.

Comment: Well, don't use a reference.  Make the function argument `int i_` instead so it is copied by value.  Look at C++11 lambda expressions to make the code modern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not the `func` object. `std::thread` will copy your functor.

> First the constructor copies/moves all arguments (both the function
>   object f and all args...) to thread-accessible storage

The issue is the reference `int& i;` your functor keeps to `some_local_state` which indeed will be invalid once `some_local_state` runs out of scope.

To solve this copy the value of `some_local_state` instead of keeping a reference to it. If you need shared access, consider using a `std::shared_ptr`.